# Why are there so many octagons in Exorcist II: The Heretic?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-exorcist-ii

Sure, there are many questions to be had regarding this movie, but why is the clinic Regan goes to made of octagons in the rooms? But especially, **why are people constantly pushing big octagons around in the background?**

This movie was difficult to pay attention to. I promise I watched the whole thing, and *maybe* they explained it, but if so I don't remember. Maybe it's in a script.

[image: I]

[image: J]

[image: H]